# custom html input box on focus issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to develop a HTML input box like the below image:

[image: Normal input].

I made it using the following **code:**

```css
input[type=text] {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
     padding: 2px 5px;
}
input[type=text]:focus
{
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #D9FFA9;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  Name :  <input type="text" />
  
</body>
</html>
```

**ISSUE:**
Here when I focus the input box, and start entering text a blue border is appearing around the input box as shown in below image.

**I have to remove this blue border box. How to do it?**
[image]

Comment: You are really being spammed with answers. Half the people who viewed this question have attempted an answer! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Add `outline: 0` to your css

```
input[type=text] :focus
{
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #D9FFA9;
    outline: 0;
}
```

I will add that this is there for a purpose and shows a user when the input is focused - It's good practice to style it (change color for example), not remove it

Answer (score 2):

Add `outline: none;` to your CSS, in `input:focus` Please note that `input[type=text]: focus` should be `input[type=text]:focus`.

See the updated snippet here:

```css
input[type=text] {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 2px 5px;
}
input[type=text]:focus
{
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #D9FFA9;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  Name :  <input type="text" />
  
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the white space between `input[type=text]` and `:focus`

And add `outline: none;` to `input[type=text]:focus`

```css
input[type=text] {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
     padding: 2px 5px;
}
input[type=text]:focus
{
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #D9FFA9;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  Name :  <input type="text" />
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add

```
outline:0;
```

or

```
outline:none;
```

in your css :)

Answer (score 0):

Added `outline:0` or `outline:none` on `input[type="text"]:focus` in your css.

```
input[type="text"]:focus{
   outline:none
}
```